# Show Text Over Android SeekBar Track

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar, seekbar-thumb

I want to show some static text over seek bar track.
It's different from what's normally required, i.e., showing current progress as tip or inside thumb.

I've tried both options of showing text; By adding a TextView over seekbar or by adding it dynamically in **onDraw()** method of my custom seekbar class.

**NORMAL VIEW:**
[image: Seekbar]

**PROBLEM VIEW:**
[image: Text appearing over thumb]

The issue is that the text is ABOVE both track and seekbar (as shown above). I somehow want to decrease the z-index of text so that it hides behind the thumb.

I'm overriding the onDraw method like:

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
    paint.setTextSize(36);
    int x = getWidth() / 2 - bounds.centerX();
    int y = getHeight() / 2 - bounds.centerY();
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
}
```

Is there a way I can hide text behind thumbnail?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Draw you thumb also, and remove the default one.

Comment: what about changing the alpha of the text depending on the Seekbar position

Comment: Isn't there a way where I can simple set z-indices of all three layers?